# How to detect a Java File Walk is a file or a folder (in Scala)?

Tags: java, scala

I have the following code in Scala that returns a tree of directories and files

```
import java.nio._
import java.nio.file._
import collection.JavaConverters._

object TestFileWalk extends App {
  val dir = FileSystems.getDefault.getPath("c://app-files") 
  Files.walk(dir).iterator().asScala.foreach(println)
}
```

Running the code above returns:

```
c:\app-files
c:\app-files\csv
c:\app-files\csv\10
c:\app-files\csv\10\Book2.csv
c:\app-files\csv\11
c:\app-files\csv\11\Book3.txt
c:\app-files\csv\12
c:\app-files\csv\9
c:\app-files\csv\9\Book1.csv
c:\app-files\csvtemp
c:\app-files\csvtemp\user1
c:\app-files\csvtemp\user1\script 2016-11-04.sql
c:\app-files\This is a folder with Uppercase
c:\app-files\This is a folder with Uppercase\File in the folder with Uppercase.csv
```

As you can see, some entries are folder names and others file names (files have extension).

How can I programmatically know if the entry is a file or a folder? I looked at [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) but cannot figure it out.

Comment: `_.isDirectory`, `_.isFile` may work.

Comment: this does not compile `Files.walk(dir).iterator().asScala.foreach(println(_.isDirectory))`

Comment: Get the `File` from it first possibly using `Path#toFile(void)` and then `isDirectory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That call

```
val dir = FileSystems.getDefault.getPath("c://app-files")
```

returns a Path object ( see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) for details ).

And the Path class provides a method `[toFile()][2]`; return a File object.
From there: the File class contains `[isDirectory()][2]`

Thus:

```
dir.toFile().isDirectory()
```

gives you what you are looking for!

And beyond that:

```
Files.walk(dir).iterator().asScala.foreach(println)
```

`walk(dir).iterator()` results in `Iterator<Path>`; so again - you have a **Path** object there; which you could transform into a File; and a File knows if it is a directory or not!

Comment: thanks for the hint, the second option worked with this code `Files.walk(dir).iterator().asScala.foreach( p => println(p.toFile().isDirectory() + " " + p))`